# How can I increase the NSStatusBar Image size?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I noticed the image size regardless of which image I use it is slitty smaller than the other apps image in macOS menu bar.

This is the code i used in cocoa:

```
private lazy var statusItem: NSStatusItem = NSStatusItem()

 statusItem = NSStatusBar.system.statusItem(withLength: NSStatusItem.variableLength)
        
if let button = statusItem.button {
    button.image = NSImage(systemSymbolName: "wifi", accessibilityDescription: "1")
}
```

How to make my image size get the same size as other apps?

The result:

[image]

Comment: Did you try replacing `NSStatusItem.variableLength` with, say, `22`?

Comment: Yes, but it is not related to issue, as we can read it says: `withLength` or `NSStatusItem.variableLength` it means length, but the issue is about height. By the way I tried your way but not helped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following source code should make the icon larger, but may be too large. You may read about it here: [`NSImageSymbolConfiguration`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsimagesymbolconfiguration)

```
// globals at top of AppDelegate
var statusItem: NSStatusItem!
var image: NSImage!

// Then in func applicationDidFinishLaunching()
statusItem = NSStatusBar.system.statusItem(withLength: NSStatusItem.variableLength)
if let button = statusItem.button {
   image = NSImage(systemSymbolName: "wifi", accessibilityDescription: "1");
   let config = NSImage.SymbolConfiguration(scale: .large)
   button.image = image.withSymbolConfiguration(config)
}
```

[image]

Comment: I think it made no deference in results.

Comment: It's clearly larger. See edited answer.